# How get parent Range of current Selection in word add-in using JavaScript API

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I need to insert a paragraph with ContentControl after the current selection paragraph, suppose the current selection is in middle of any paragraph, table or CC, I need to insert a new paragraph with CC after that.

I have tried below code to get the current selection and set range to end of that then will insert the paragraph after it:

```
var range = context.document.getSelection().getRange("end");
range.insertParagraph("","After");
```

but it insert the Paragraph after the current Selection, not after current selection parent.

Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are observing is by design. You are getting the range of the selection. What you need to do is to get the range of the paragraph and then add another after.

All ranges have a paragraphs collection, the first paragraph will the the paragraph containing the selection, so you can get tit by calling:

context.document.getSelection().paragraphs.getFirst().getRange().insertParagraph("",after");

the full code sample would look like this:

```js
Word.run(async (context) => {
            var myParagraph = context.document.getSelection().paragraphs.getFirst().getRange().insertParagraph("", "after")
            myParagraph.insertContentControl();
            return context.sync();
        })
    
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    })
```

Note: if the selection expands more than one paragraph, probably you would need to do a getLast() instead of a getFirst(), but i am not sure your exact scenario.

thanks!